# How can I find the taxonomy in edited_{taxonomy}?

Tags: taxonomy, terms

How do I find out which taxonomy triggered the save?

```
add_action ( 'edited_' . $taxonomy->name, 'save_taxonomy' );

function save_taxonomy( $term_id )
{
    $term = get_term( $term_id, $taxonomy ); // Where can I get the taxonomy?
}
```

Comment: One way is to used the passed `taxonomy_id` which you do not have ( [See Code Reference `tt_id`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/edited_taxonomy/) ) and run an SQL Query on the ID to pull the Taxonomy Slug. I don't have a database hand to test any SQL statements though.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work, don't know if it's the correct approach.

```
add_action ( 'edited_' . $taxonomy->name, function( $term_id ) use ( $taxonomy ) {
     $term = get_term( $term_id, $taxonomy->name ); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the action `edited_term` instead. It fires immediately before `edited_$taxonomy` and you get the taxonomy as an argument.

```
add_action( 'edited_term', function( $term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy ) {
    // Do something.
}, 10, 3 );
```